# How to shift a list nth time in Left or Right and fill it up with 0 in python

Tags: python

I have a list: `[6,7,8,9,10]` , Now I want to shift it 2 times to the right and replace the shifted position by `0`. The output will be something like : `[0,0,6,7,8]`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it directly:

```
>>> a = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> [0, 0] + a[:3]
[0, 0, 6, 7, 8]
```

To shift it by a variable number of positions `n`:

```
>>> [0]*n + a[:len(a)-n]
```

Appropriate bounds checking is up to you (try `n=6` to with a 5-element list for an unexpected result).

Comment: Thanks Greg! This is indeed possible. Actually this is a simple example, I have to do it for a dynamic list. I was looking for a inbuilt function like rotate rather. Is it possible ?

Comment: `a[:len(a) - n]` is equivalent to `a[:-n]`.

Comment: @DibyenduDutta: If you're looking for a function that does something very similar, try [`numpy.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> def lpadzero(s, n):
...     return [0] * n + s[:-n]
>>> lpadzero(s, 2)
[0, 0, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slice operation.

```
>>> a = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> del a[-2:]
>>> a[:0] = [0, 0]
>>> a
[0, 0, 6, 7, 8]
```

You can also use [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) if you want fixed size array.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> a = deque([6,7,8,9,10], maxlen=5)
>>> a
deque([6, 7, 8, 9, 10], maxlen=5)
>>> a.extendleft([0, 0])
>>> a
deque([0, 0, 6, 7, 8], maxlen=5)
```